# Issues setting up TINC on Mac OSX 10.12.2

Tags: mac-osx, tap, tun, tinc

I have TINC setup on a few linux boxes and they are working great.

- linux001 (static ip vps - 10.0.0.1)
- macosx002 (connects to linux001 - 10.0.0.2)
- linux050 (connects to linux001 - 10.0.0.50)

I also have a Mac with OSX 10.12.2 that seems to be connected to linux001 but can not communicate.  I got it to the point its at by starting with [this  guide on tinc-vpn.org](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/examples/osx-install/).  In the process of following the guide, I ran into an issue where there where no /dev/tun0 or /dev/tap0 ... after quite a bit of googling I found and installable package of [tuntaposx](http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/development.xhtml) on sourceforge since homebrew and macports failed when attempting to install there versions of the same package.

So, currently macosx002 seems to connect to linux001

```
Sending PING to linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655): 8
Sending 2 bytes of metadata to linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655)
Flushing 2 bytes to linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655)
Got PING from linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655): 8
Sending PONG to linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655): 9
Sending 2 bytes of metadata to linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655)
Flushing 2 bytes to linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655)
Got PONG from linux001 (x.x.x.x port 655): 9
```

However, when I attempt to ping macosx002 from linux001 I get the following error:

```
Error while writing to Generic BSD tun device /dev/tun0: Input/output error
Error while writing to Generic BSD tun device /dev/tun0: Input/output error
Error while writing to Generic BSD tun device /dev/tun0: Input/output error
Error while writing to Generic BSD tun device /dev/tun0: Input/output error
```

If I attempt to ping in the other direction I get the following error:

```
user-mac-mini:~ user$ ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

This leads me to believe that tincd is infact connecting both ways ... but there is something wrong with routing to tun/tap on the macosx002

If I go to /dev/ both tun0 and tap0 do in fact exist but only when I install the package from sourceforge ... if I install the package via macports, homebrew, or make install ... tun0 and tap0 do not exist.

Any help would be appreciated ... if I end up finding the answer on my own first I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511998/3259258) awesome post I changed my `tinc-up` file to:

```
ifconfig tun0 inet 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1 up netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Now I can ping and SSH to and from .1 and .2